# Spring data for Amazon DynamoDB

Tags: spring, spring-data, amazon-dynamodb

We are starting to use Amazon web services.  As I was searching for a Spring library, but couldn't find anything.  Is this a case of there has been a decision made to not include this functionality or has no one provided any code.  Is there any interested in having a spring-data-dynamodb?

Comment: [Oh come on man. Really?](https://github.com/michaellavelle/spring-data-dynamodb)

Comment: @BranislavLazic What do you mean?

Comment: There are still no really good tutorials in this area.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

there are plenty of examples out of there. Take a look at this one: It should be very interesting: https://github.com/michaellavelle/spring-data-dynamodb

**[UPDATE]**

That project is out to date right now, you should use this one: https://github.com/derjust/spring-data-dynamodb

Comment: That is one of the examples that I found.  My question is, Is there some reason why there isn't an official module?

Comment: Well, spring data projects are divided into main modules, community modules and Related modules. Most of the main modules are open source based tools. Community modules are implemented by the spring community and one of those community modules is this repository: https://github.com/michaellavelle/spring-data-dynamodb. You can check this page for reference: http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/

Comment: @m-situation Unfortunately, that project says that it hasn't been undergoing development since January 2016 and a fork has taken on the support, but that one isn't listed on the Spring Data page.  I guess I don't understand the purpose of the Community modules.

Comment: Community modules category identifies modules that are external to the Spring data project. They are provided by individual developers or private companies and have their own licenses as well as their own versioning system. Issues and bug reports can usually be reported on their own repositories. I think you should simply follow the fork: https://github.com/derjust/spring-data-dynamodb. This project is continuously maintaned and seems stable. Maybe it will be released soon by the community

Comment: @m-situation.  Thank you for the info.  That is what I needed.

Comment: Thanks @M.Situation for this excellent explanation. Author of https://github.com/derjust/spring-data-dynamodb here -
I asked the Spring team to update the link: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1226 - Even though I'm just standing on the shoulders of Michael, he won't continue the project so I hope this will ease any confusion